# How can I print a locally stored JSONstringify object into html?

Tags: javascript, html

If I have:

```
var Store = localStorage("Storage", JSON.stringify({
  name: "Bob",
  age: 30
}));
```

How can I print the contents using JavaScript?
I also asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502969/how-to-load-the-localstorage-json-strinigfy-objects-to-html-rows, but so far no responses. I'm trying to simplify my question more here.

Comment: What about `alert(localStorage.getItem('Storage'))`? You can replace the alert part with anything else to print out as HTML or whatever.

Comment: I don't think `localStorage` is a function. Displaying data in HTML is as simple as `document.getElementById('yourOutputElement').textContent = jsonString;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call .getItem() or .setItem() on the localStorage object.

**To save an object**

```
localStorage.setItem('Storage', JSON.stringify({ name: 'Bob', age: 30}));
```

**To retrieve an object**

```
var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Storage'));
```

**To print an item that was already saved in local storage**

```
var obj = localStorage.getItem('Storage'); // Get the item
console.log(obj) // The item is currently a String
console.dir(JSON.parse(obj)) // JSON.parse converts the String into an Object
```

Answer (score 0):

localStorage is not a function. It's a simple object, which can be "stringified".

To set storage value, write : `localStorage[ "Storage" ] = { name: "Bob", age: 30 };`

To get it, write :
`var Store = JSON.stringify( localStorage[ "Storage" ] );`

Then to print it :
`document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = Store;`